# Angular - upload/store/download a file with base64

Tags: angular, download, base64

I am using angular and trying to upload a file (store in database) and then download the file. I am using base 64 encoding/decoding. It looks like it's working but after I download the file, when I try to open it with windows the default image viewer, it says "It looks like we dont support this format." The file isn't blank (size is > 0).
Where am I going wrong? One thing that seems suspicious to me is that my variable decode is showing in the debugger as type [object ArrayBuffer] rather than a string.

//Read in the file like this (e.g. a jpeg file):

```
   let fileReader = new FileReader();

    // Callback fxn for when the filereader's onload event fires (readAsBinaryString() below)
    fileReader.onload = async (e) => {

      // base64 encode the file contents
      let encoded = btoa(fileReader.result as string);
      // pass the encoded file content, type, and name to the API

      //store the file (i.e. encoded) to the database
  //Note that I compared this value to the value I retrieve from the database below and they are the same
    }

    // Now read the file contents. Note that this is an async operation and the onload callback will be called when it completes
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(documentName);
```

//retrieve it
let documentName = 'test.jpg';
let encodedDocument = xxx; //the encoded string from the database, which matches what was saved to the database earlier
let documentFormat = 'image/jpeg';
let decoded = atob(encodedDocument);

```
    //download it
    const blob = new Blob([decoded], { type: documentFormat });
    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = documentName;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    a.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured it out. atob wasn't working somehow.
The key was to use this url to download it.
let url = 'data:' + documentFormat + ';charset=utf-8;base64,' + encodedDocument;